# Веб-приложение, не работает бд

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Запускаю веб-приложение, php работает, mysql тоже. Открывается, но нету данных. Будто не видит бд. Подключал правильно. В веб инспекторе показывает на бд (на скрине). Вот так подключал бд
`<?php $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_account"); ?>`

Скрин с инспектора
[image: Подозрительная штука]

А так же, скрин как должно быть и как у меня :(
[image: Как должно быть]

[image: Как у меня]

Comment: *Вот так подключал бд* И как, подключил? вероятно, нет... что вернулось в `$con`?

Comment: Оказалось проблема в phpmyadmin, переустановил и сбросил пароль root пользователя. Все заработало